# wordpress wp_enqueue_script is not working in actions but working normally .

Tags: wordpress

```
 add_action("publish_post", "php_func");

 function php_func(){
     wp_register_script("customscript","link to js file");
     wp_enqueue_script("customerscript")

 }
```

I think above process is right, but thats not working . The two lines in above func are working normally when written in the php file directly(without actions), but with actions, above is not working .

```
 function php_func(){
     echo "<script>alert("hiii");</script>"; //working but not good method. Also, getting errors like headers sent already .
 }
```

Comment: Note that the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook will not fire unless the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` function has been called explicitly (usually via the `header.php` page).

Answer (score 0):

Every action is registered to a specific hook. When that hook is reached in the code, all actions registered to that hook is run.

When you publish a post the `publish_post` hook will run you function, and enqueue you javascript.

Your problem is that the code, then loops through all enqueued scripts and run them, has already been run.

You need to enqueue them in an earlier hook. And the specific hook build for this is called `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "php_func");

function php_func(){
    wp_register_script("customscript","link to js file");
    wp_enqueue_script("customerscript")
}
```

There is a lot more information to be found in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: In which way? Doesn't the script get loaded at all, are you not entering your php_func() or are, whatever you want that function to do, not happening?

Comment: php_func() is being called, but nothing happening.

Comment: In your example code you have `"customscript"` and `"customerscript"` these needs to be equal.